# how can i modify html report so that i can print passed and failed test case name in html report in jasmine framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor

[image]

I want to print a custom message with passed, Thanks in advance

Comment: which jasmine reporter package you are calling for reporting?

Answer (score 1):

### I have done it . We may use Jasmine Custom Matchers

We can override the default messaging in the [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) reporter by defining the [custom matcher](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/custom_matcher.html) in the global scope and overriding the default message variable as follows:

```js
    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toReport: function () {
                return {
                    compare: function (actual, expected, msg) {
                        var result = {pass: actual == expected};
                        result.message = msg;
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

And it can be used in expect statements like below inside err function block:

```js
expect(true).toReport(true, "Perform operation X succesfully because of " + customSuccessMessage);
```

```js
expect(false).toReport(true, "Unable to perform required operation because of " + err.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine documentation explains how to create a custom reporter: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_reporter

However, maybe there is already some that you can use (or modify) to fit your needs. See the following:

[jasmine-reporters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-reporters)

[jasmine-console-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-console-reporter)